Rundeck take output from NODE1 and run a command on itself to send data on NODE2
I have a job in Rundeck v5.2.0, that runs a PowerShell script on remote 'NODE1' and outputs either 'True' or 'False'. I want to use "Invoke-WebRequest" to send that output to 'NODE2'. But 'NODE1' doesn't have access on 'NODE2'. The Rundeck server does have access on 'NODE2' though.
So, I have to somehow save the output from 'NODE1' and create another step or job in Rundeck, that will take the output from 'NODE1' and run "Invoke-WebRequest" to send it on 'NODE2'.
To be clear, Rundeck has to take the output from the job that was run on 'NODE1' and run a PowerShell script on itself, to send the output on 'NODE2'.
How can I do this?

Two jobs: the first one dispatched to the node00, executes a command, and stores the result in a data value. In this job, you can call another job (via the job reference step) dispatched to node01 with a specific option, this option "receives" the data value from the first job.
I made an example (tested on Rundeck 5.2).
JobONE:
- defaultTab: nodes
  description: ''
  executionEnabled: true
  id: 6eeb1cdc-b17d-4c05-9511-a80cdea2212a
  loglevel: INFO
  name: JobONE
  nodeFilterEditable: false
  nodefilters:
    dispatch:
      excludePrecedence: true
      keepgoing: false
      rankOrder: ascending
      successOnEmptyNodeFilter: false
      threadcount: '1'
    filter: node00
  nodesSelectedByDefault: true
  plugins:
    ExecutionLifecycle: {}
  scheduleEnabled: true
  sequence:
    commands:
    - exec: echo "universe"
      plugins:
        LogFilter:
        - config:
            invalidKeyPattern: \s|\$|\{|\}|\\
            logData: 'true'
            name: mydata
            regex: (.*)
            replaceFilteredResult: 'false'
          type: key-value-data
    - jobref:
        args: -myoption ${data.mydata}
        group: ''
        name: JobTWO
        nodeStep: 'true'
        uuid: fa0e282d-7ebe-4d88-bf10-709cfd4c0fb2
    keepgoing: false
    strategy: node-first
  uuid: 6eeb1cdc-b17d-4c05-9511-a80cdea2212a

JobTWO:
- defaultTab: nodes
  description: ''
  executionEnabled: true
  id: fa0e282d-7ebe-4d88-bf10-709cfd4c0fb2
  loglevel: INFO
  name: JobTWO
  nodeFilterEditable: false
  nodefilters:
    dispatch:
      excludePrecedence: true
      keepgoing: false
      rankOrder: ascending
      successOnEmptyNodeFilter: false
      threadcount: '1'
    filter: node01
  nodesSelectedByDefault: true
  options:
  - name: myoption
    value: world
  plugins:
    ExecutionLifecycle: {}
  scheduleEnabled: true
  sequence:
    commands:
    - exec: echo "hello ${option.myoption}"
    keepgoing: false
    strategy: node-first
  uuid: fa0e282d-7ebe-4d88-bf10-709cfd4c0fb2

Check the result here.
